# Clojure alter update-in returns nil and dosync doesnt allow recur

Tags: clojure, hashmap, apply, stm, update-in

EDIT:

`dosync` creates itself a function so calls to `recur` get interpreted as calls made to the function `dosync` generated.

This is the footprint of the function I actually made. Kept it as simple as possible, I think.

```
(defn change-to-ref [ref data]
  (dosync
    (if-let [[new-ref new-data] (some-test @ref data)]
      (recur new-ref new-data)
      (alter ref f data))))
```

The Exception:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Mismatched argument count to recur, expected: 0 args, got: 2
```

ORIGINAL:

I was trying to update a hashmap in a ref as follows

```
(def example-ref (ref {:some {:nested {:structure}}}))
(defn f [this] [this])  ;; just an example function

(sync (alter example-ref update-in [:some] f)

user=> nil
```

Which was quite surprising as it should've returned

```
user=> {:some [{:nested {:structure}}]}
```

So than I tried:

```
(update-in @example-ref [:some] f)

user=> {:some [{:nested {:structure}}]}
```

But than I read that `alter`calls `apply` so:

```
(apply update-in @example-ref '([:some] f))

user=> {:some nil}
```

Okay, so lets do it the proper way:

```
(apply update-in @example-ref (list [:some] f))

user=> {:some [{:nested {:structure}}]}
```

Well it's great I figured this out,
but it doesn't  explain why this goes wrong in `alter`
and I can't even change it anyways...

```
(apply (fn [a b] (update-in a b f)) @example-ref '([:something]))

user=> {:some [{:nested {:structure}}]}
```

It looks terrible but atleast it works and I can *simulate* it for `alter` :D

```
(sync (alter example-ref (fn [a b] (update-in a b f)) [:some])

user=> nil
```

Ok, you win.

I took a look at:
[clojure.lang.Ref.alter source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Ref.java#L169)
but have grown none the wiser. (other than, that to my understanding, `alter` actually doesn't call `apply`)

I hope some of you will understand this and have an answer as to what is the proper code.

Comment: What do you mean when using `recur` within `dosync`? Do you really want nested transactions there?

Comment: @OlegTheCat I actually do yes, I have a nested structure of refs and want to find the last one within a path so I van change it, the problem is resolved btw simply by making sure theres a function call within dosync.

Comment: @OlegTheCat btw I agree with your question if I would run a transaction and then recur, that wouldn't be a good idea, since the transaction always is a single one (in tail position) I think this is fine, maybe its nicer if I made a seperate pure function for searching in a path

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that signature of [`sync`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sync) is as follows:

> (sync flags-ignored-for-now & body)

First argument of this macro is ignored. Also documentation recommends to pass `nil` for it:

> transaction-flags => TBD, pass nil for now

So, correct way of using `sync` would be:

```
> (sync nil (alter example-ref update-in [:some] (partial conj [])))
{:some [{:nested {:structure :foo}}]}
```

I'd also recommend to use `dosync` instead of `sync` (just not to mess with the first parameter; essentially these functions [are the same](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/4ff462372c29ff2bc22b4d39962ad526f7e2c73d/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4880)):

```
> (dosync (alter example-ref update-in [:some] (partial conj [])))
{:some [{:nested {:structure :foo}}]}
```

Comment: Actually I used dosync before, but that gave an error about recur being called with the wrong amount of args, read that dosync makes an anonymous function, do you know how to get around this?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put MCVE that causes the issue with `dosync`?